# how to call a function in _cdecl convention from a code in _stdcall convention

Tags: visual-c++

I have a vc++ dll in _cdecl calling convention. I want to use the exported function of that dll from the code in _stdcall calling convention. I m getting the linker error as expected. But how can i do that.

Comment: right click on project go to properties->Linker->input->additional dependency write your dll in this field and apply ok.

Comment: Specify the calling convention explicitly (using `__cdecl` keyword) in the function prototype in the header your `__stdcall`-compiled code includes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have sources to the stdcall DLL, You could load dynamically and specify the calling convention on the function pointer, otherwise project setting is used. Don't do this:

```
BOOL (*pBeep)(UINT) = 0; // defaults to project calling convention setting (/Gd etc)
```

If your project is set to __cdecl which is default, you'd actually want to explicitly set the function pointer to __stdcall:

```
BOOL (__stdcall *pBeep)(UINT) = 0;
```

make sure to cast correctly when assigning the function pointer as well:

```
pBeep = (BOOL (__stdcall *)(UINT))GetProcAddress(beepLibrary, "MessageBeep");
```